# how to do include within include statement

Tags: c, programming-languages

I wanted to include a file say a.h in my program which is located at some location say (/ws/uname/bd/lib) & that file in turn has different include statements whose files are located in vastly different locations. 
How can i do that by just including the file with "/ws/uname/bd/lib/a.h". 
I dont want to change any of the header file.

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 5):

What compiler are you using?  If it's clang or gcc, you can use the `-I` flag to add search paths for header files.  From the [`gcc(1)` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc):

> **-I***dir*
>
> Add the directory *dir* to the head of the list of directories to be searched for header files. This can be used to override a system header file, substituting your own version, since these directories are searched before the system header file directories. However, you should not use this option to add directories that contain vendor-supplied system header files (use **-isystem** for that). If you use more than one **-I** option, the directories are scanned in left-to-right order; the standard system directories come after.

Comment: I tried -i option it doesnt seeem to work in this case , the .h files are dispersed all over .

Comment: @Vinay, then you just need to add more `-I` flags.  Once you have all the directories you need to look in, it will work.

Comment: but each include fiile has several further includes ..
I dont want to specify each & every path. it seems tedious

Comment: If they're in subdirectories of one "main" directory, you can use `-I/my/include/path` and then do things like `#include "subdir1/file1.h"` and `#include "subdir2/file2.h"`. If they're not in the same subdirectory, then you'll need to list them all, tedious or not.

Comment: +1 @Graeme - computers only do what you tell them to do, not what you want them to do.

Comment: @Vinay: I'm curious - if you don't tell the compiler where it should find headers, how is it supposed to find them?  If you just let it search your whole filesystem, you'd never be able to control what version of the header it would pickup (so you'd better have only one copy of `a.h` on your whole system).  Not to mention that it might hurt build times...

Comment: @Michael , i have only one copy of a.h but a. includes multiple header files.